# If R is a ring with idempotent then eR is clean ring if and only if eRe is clean ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, nilpotence, idempotents

I am reading this paper on clean rings: [*Clean general rings*, by W.K. Nicholson, Y. Zhou](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869305000591), and I am puzzled by the proof of Corollary 11:

> **Corollary 11.** If $R$ is a ring and $e^2=e \in R$, then $eR$ is a clean general ring if and only if $eRe$ is a clean ring.
> **Proof.** Observe that the map $\theta: eR \to eRe$ given by $\theta(x)=xe$ is an onto ring morphism with kernel $K=eR(1-e)$. Hence $eR/K \cong eRe$ and $K^2=0$. If $eRe$ is clean this implies that $eR$ is clean by Theorem 10; conversely if $eR$ is clean so is its image $eRe$. $\square$

I would appreciate any clarification on the following:

- What is a ring morphism, did the writer mean a ring homomorphism? If so, how did they prove that the mapping preserved the multiplication? (i.e. $\phi(xy)=\phi(x) \cdot \phi(y)$)
- Additionally, they mentioned that every element in $K$ (the kernel) is a nilpotent element, in what way did this benefit the proof?
- Lastly, they conclude that if $eRe$ is clean, this implies that $eR$ is clean by Theorem 10:

> **Theorem 10.** Let $I$ be a general ring and let $A \lhd I$.
> (1) If $I$ is clean, then $A$ and $I/A$ are both clean and idempotents lift modulo $A$.
> (2) The converse is true if $A \subseteq J$ or if all primitive factors of $I$ are artinian.

In what manner did the theorem aid the proof?

I look forward to any elucidation you can provide on these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is a ring morphism, did the writter mean a ring homomorphism?

Yes, morphism and homomorphism usually mean the same thing.

> if so how did they prove that the mapping preserved the multiplication?
>
> (i.e.) ϕ(xy)=ϕ(x)⋅ϕ(y)

That's actually quite easy once you introduce $\xi,\eta\in R$ with $x=e\xi$ and $y=e\eta$.

> additionally, they mentiond that every element in K (the kerenl) is a
> nilpotent element, in what way did this benefit the proof?
>
> lastly the conclude that if eRe is clean this implies that eR is clean
> by [theorem 10][3] in what manner did the theorem aid the proof.

It seems that they want to use Theorem 10(2), and $K^2=0$ implies $K\subset J$, because nilpotent ideals are contained in the Jacobson radical $J$. The last fact I found [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Nilpotent_ideal), I'm not an expert.

Comment: ϕ(xy)=ϕ(eξ.eη)=ϕ(eξeη)=(eξeη)e but ϕ(x).ϕ(y)=ϕ(eξ).ϕ(eξeη)=eξe.eηe , can u tell me where is this wrong?

Comment: @thewizardofmath There's nothing wrong. These two terms are the same because of $e^2=e$ (and associativity).

Comment: (Actually, you made a copying error in the second term of the second chain of equalities, but you obviously meant the right thing.)

Comment: I see. Also I did more research and I found out you were correct nilpotent elements are always in the Jacobson radical, thank you.

Comment: @thewizardofmath You're welcome. But, as Amateur_Algebraist wrote in a now deleted comment, the fact about the nilpotent elements is not true in general for noncommutative rings. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179761/nilpotent-element-and-jacobson-radical).